# My grade is 2.1 in my country but first class in the country I want to study in, how will I be treated?

Tags: graduate-admissions, grades

I've got another year of undergrad studies left and am looking for good masters degrees, but am having trouble estimating where I stand in terms of candidacy, I'll work with the British system as an example of a foreign system, as it's more likely to be familiar to everyone:

I project I'll get my diploma with a 7.1 to 7.5 out of 10, depending on the last year's test results, which in my country is upper second class (according to the conversion tables I've found), but in most countries I've found interesting degrees in, it's first class honors (or something like that, I find the exact names hard to remember and beyond the point of these systems). There are a few more differences, some in favor (we have lower average grades which puts the same grade in a higher percentile) and some against me (we have a higher passing grade, 5 instead of 4, so they're grades would be theoretically dragged down if we assumed an even distribution in both countries), and my big advantage is a very strong CV in terms of experience and a very good internship, also it's a 5 year diploma that I'm finishing, with 300 ECTS, but not exactly an integrated masters.

**TL;DR / The Question:** So how do universities view foreign students' degrees? Do they look at the grade alone or do they take the conversion based on titles for granted? Also, does the percentile in which you finish count? If so I'm in luck since we have uncharacteristically poor grades here.

P.S, seeing the message on the "graduate-admissions" tag, field of study is Computer Engineering, location, as "diploma" may have suggested, southern Europe. Also, though I state my situation to illustrate my concerns, do notice that my question is indeed fairly (in my humble opinion) clear and generally applicable rather than personal and generic, just in case.

Comment: My experience going from Brazil (MS) to France (phd) was that those details were totally ignored. My phd advisor knew the lab I was during my MS and unicamp's reputation. I don't think he ever saw any transcript (or even the MS diploma - I sent the B. Eng. for the university for paperwork, that's it).

Comment: That's quite an encouraging encouraging start, I hope that's the general case

Comment: I know people in the admissions teams and I myself come from Spain, where grades work similar as you describe. No worries, admissions people know, it should not be a problem. Also, often they look more to rec letter and other things rather than the GPA